# Allow scroll with mouse but don't show browser scrollbars?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a Form with a Web Browser, I don't want to show the scrollbars in the web browser, but I want to allow the user to scroll down the website with the mouse wheel.

How can I do it ?

Thanks.

Comment: Remember to mark a question as the answer if it solved your problem.  If none of the questions helped you.  Post what your current problems are.

Comment: @DadeLamkins Marked, I couldn't test it until now so I didn't know if it was OK.

Comment: Did it work?  I know it did when I tested, did it work for your purposes though?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT**

After much work, I've gotten a solution!

I used VB.net and then converted it over to C#:

```
private void WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    WebBrowser1.Document.Body.Style = "overflow:hidden";
    HtmlElement head = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    HtmlElement scriptEl = WebBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("script");
    scriptEl.SetAttribute("language", "javascript");
    scriptEl.InnerHtml = My.Resources.TextFile1;
    head.AppendChild(scriptEl);
}
```

Now, add this text file to your resources (or wherever).

```
function handle(delta) {
        window.scrollBy(0,-delta*20)
}

function wheel(event){
        var delta = 0;
        if (!event)
                event = window.event;
        if (event.wheelDelta) {
                delta = event.wheelDelta/120;
        }
        if (delta)
                handle(delta);
        if (event.preventDefault)
                event.preventDefault();
    event.returnValue = false;
}

if (window.addEventListener)
    window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = wheel;
```

Now, on the line where it says `scriptEl.innherHtml = My.Resources.TextFile1;`, just put in the second file (the javascript).

On the line `window.scrollBy(0,-delta*20)`, change the 20 to whatever number you feel best represents normal scrolling.  20 felt decent to me.

The C# code needs to be put inside of the 'DocumentComplete' event for your WebBrowser object.

Hope that helps!  It worked for me :)

Comment: That disables the mouse wheel :)

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for mentioning that.  I didn't even bother testing.  Nice catch.  I've updated it with a solution that works...