# C# WebBrowser disable and hide scrollbar

Tags: c#, javascript, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have `WebBrowser` control in my `Form`. and i allow `JavaScript` that call a method in the C# form :

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public class ScriptManager
{
            // Variable to store the form of type Form1.
        private Form1 mForm;

        // Constructor.
        public ScriptManager(Form1 form)
        {
            // Save the form so it can be referenced later.
            mForm = form;
        }

        // This method can be called from JavaScript.
        public void EnterFullScreenMode()
        {
            // Call a method on the form.
            mForm.EnterFullScreenMode();
        }

      }
```

And in the form i include this method :

```
public void EnterFullScreenMode()
{
    browser.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
}
```

And i noticed that when i call this method to remove the scroll bar of the `WebBrowser` the page is refresh and the scroll bar still there.
Any idea what is the issue? There is any other way to hide and disable scrolllbar?

Comment: Have a [look](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11678973/hide-scrollbars-in-the-the-webbrowser-control) at this qustion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internally, `browser.ScrollBarsEnabled` is provisioned as [DOCHOSTUIFLAG_SCROLL_NO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753277%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) flag via [IDocHostUIHandler::GetHostInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753257%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The `WebBrowser` object has to reload the document for the new value to be picked up.

I'd suggest setting `browser.ScrollBarsEnabled` to `false` for once, after `InitializeComponent()` in your form, then control the scrolling with CSS: `<body style="overflow: auto">...</body>` will make scrollbars automatic, and `style="overflow: hidden"` will make them disappear.